# Addresses with 0x at the beginning

Tags: memory-address

In some kind of applications that I used to "change" something in the executable files requires a proper addresses with the `0x` in the beginning. For example: `0x2FF0C4`.

The question is, what are those addresse and how can I get them?

I've searched a lot before creating this question, but the `address` phrase in the search engines provides large amount of records, because I don't know the way, how can I 'name' it.

I guess it's some kind of memory address ?

Comment: `0x` denotes [Hexadecimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't beat Rouhani's simple answer but here's a little more information on memory addresses:

"Addresses" on computers are usually assumed to be "memory addresses" that identify locations on RAM. By convention, locations on RAM are denoted by hexadecimal because they are commonly encountered in powers of two i.e. pages; thus, it's arithmetic is easier with hexadecimal.

Edit: I realized that you answered your own question.

Comment: Thank you. Thats the answer I expected :). Could you please also tell me , how can I search if an address exists in a executable?

Comment: @Cyclone That's a trick question. All addresses exist on every executable. When you run an executable, a virtual address space is created for them. It's "virtual" because it's not directly mapped to the entire, contiguous block of physical memory. The entire topic falls under memory architecture which is beyond the scope of comments. Please see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory for more.

Comment: Yea, I understand that. But I got one executable file, and there is an `0x2FF0C4` address, so how can I find this address (in a hex editor maybe?) to see , whats behind that?

Comment: Yes, you can find the address through a hex editor; however, depending on the memory address given, the value may change as the application goes on e.g. a game. Assuming your implied intentions, I would try CheatEngine for whatever reason you want to seek or change values held in memory. Here's a video tutorial on simple memory architecture, C++ and CheatEngine I made last year if you're interested in that stuff: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I0zPwg4iUDk

Comment: Well, CheatEngine will change the values temporary (until the application close), I want to change it permamently, in the hex editor. Atm. I'm going to change `experience` that player receive ingame while killing a monster. I'm forced to change such things via hex editor, as I dont have the source code... So could you tell me, how can I find the address through the hex editor? Anyway, thanks for the video - I'll add this to my 'helpful list'.

Comment: It is guaranteed that changing that specific memory address through a hex editor will provide more experience when killing monsters. In fact, it may break the game entirely. Regardless, you could try Hex Workshop ($90) or HxD (free). Since I don't use hex editors, I wouldn't know where to start but I assume there's a "search" button/menu after loading up the game in the hex editor that you can use.

Comment: @Cyclone Depends on where the game keeps the information. Most likely games will keep inforamtion and such in separate files altogether. The exe will then load those at runtime. You can really only safely change values at runtime and a discussion of doing that is a separate question altogether. Finding an address in an executable statically is not easily achieved as due to address randomization you are not guaranteed specific addresses, only offsets from certain locations.

Comment: `HxD` its what I've installed some days ago and yes, there is a search box to search for: `text` or `hex`, everything I choose, there are 0 matches for the search string: `0x2FF0C4` or `2FF0C4`.

Comment: @Cyclone I can't help you with anything program-specific but intuition tells me that you should be searching for hex and not "strings".

Comment: @GioBorje Thats what I'm doing :p.